# How can show the "Action Bar Sherlock" for only a moment to let the user know that it exists?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to show for only an instant "Action Bar Sherlock" when a user enters a "Layout", is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to your ActionBar in the following way:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
```

then you can hide or show it however you wish (if you want to hide it after a certain amount of time, you could set a timer, then issue the hide() command).

```
bar.show();
```

or

```
bar.hide();
```